# React i18next modify translation file path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, translation, i18next

I am using a react application with react-i18next and I am loading the translation from the path

```
locales/en/translation.json
locales/de/translation.json
locales/fr/translation.json
...
```

Can I change the path and have the translations loaded from

```
lib/en.i18n.json
lib/de.i18n.json
lib/fr.i18n.json
...
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the configuration of your i18n library.

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';

i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .init({
    backend: {
      loadPath: 'lib/{{lng}}.i18n.json',
    },
    // ... other i18n options ...
  });
```